# "Er ist ein Kick-, Beat- und Boxer"

Tags: phrase, grammaticality, punctuation, list

Bei Aufzählungen kann man ja einen Bindestrich verwenden, wenn das Grundwort gleich ist.
z.B

> Er ist Kick- und Beatboxer.

Aber darf man das auch, wenn beim letzten Aufzählungselement das Grundwort das gesamte Wort ist? Z. B.:

> Er ist Kick- und Boxer.
>   Er ist Kick-, Beat- und Boxer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Nein, das kann man so nicht sagen. Es müsste irgendein von den anderen Begriffen abweichender Term dabeistehen. Allerdings muss das nicht zwingend der vordere Bestandteil des Hauptwortes sein, es funktioniert auch mit einem Adjektiv:

> Er ist Kick-, Beat- und normaler Boxer.

Comment: Ich vermute das liegt daran, dass man was braucht, wo man die Hauptbetonung hintun kann. Man betont ja dann "normaler" mehr als "Boxer"

Comment: mit adjektiv hörts sich wirklich besser an. Danke